# Solr 7.1: Querying Double field for any value not possible with * anymore

Tags: apache, solr

I recently upgraded from Solr 6.6 to 7.1 and cannot query Double fields for any value anymore using

```
q: test_d:*
```

(zero results although the field is set). However,

```
q: test_d:[* TO *]
```

works. This seems to affect all numeric field types (tested for Integers, Floats and Doubles). For String, Text, Boolean fields the single asterisk works just fine like before.

Is it possbile to reconfigure Solr to have the old behavior or do I have to rewrite all queries and introduce a switch for numeric field types? Until now, no field value type differentiation was needed (which is good!).

*Minimal Working Example*

Use the `example-DIH-solr` core supplied with the Solr distributable, push the document

```
{"id":"foo","test_b":true,"test_i":42,"test_f":42.0,"test_d":42.0}
```

and use

```
q: test_b:*
q: test_d:*
q: test_i:*
q: test_f:*
```

Only the query for the Boolean field will yield a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double field definition changed. To restore the old behaviour you can use / change this:

```
<dynamicField name="*_d"  type="double" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
```

and add back the double field type definition to the schema:

```
<fieldType name="double" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
```

This worked in the past but most likely per accident - see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-11746 for a bug report / solr issue to track this.

Comment: Where did you found the documentation about this change? I'm also having problems with 7.1 version. My query does not return any results and I want to check all the changes to compare with my schema.xml file. Thanks

Comment: Missed your question, sorry. It was a fluke in the past - so there is no doc change about that at all because it was never supported so they did not document it, see the linked ticket. But time past and now its fixed in 8.5 and 9.0, see the ticket for details :).